# How get the cell data from excel where some value matched?

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

So as you see in the below screenshot i want to get the all Test Case ID store in array where run mode = No

How do i do that? 
how to iterate through the sheet and store the values ?

Any solution will be appritiated?
here is my code:

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
private static int findRow(HSSFSheet sheet, String cellContent) {
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals("No")) {
                    //not able to developed further need to store the value of the first column if matched
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: *Any solution will be appritiated?* — That requires your effort to be shown here. What have you done so far? What does not work? If you want a general advice on how to do that, I can give you a hint: Use [apache.poi](https://poi.apache.org/) and just iterate through the lines and columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't check every cell in a row.
instead check `row[2]`(Run Mode) and if satisfies the condition get value of `row[1]`(Description).

You don't need to skip first row, because it doesn't satisfy your condition.

Comment: row or cell you have mention row?

Comment: as the 4th line of your code a row contains many cells so row[1] is a cell.

Comment: i want the value of the Test case id needs to be stored so for that what do i do?

Comment: i mean you need just on for loop and inside that you can use my suggestion.

Comment: for that purpose simply use row[0]

Comment: quite gave me the idea

Comment: if it helped, check the answer as accepted. thanks.

Comment: not like accepted but gave me an idea otherwise you don't have to ask that?.

Answer (score 2):

You have to skip the first row. Don't need to iterate through each cells of the row. Use getCell(2) to check the Run Mode. And if that condition satisfies, use getCell(0) to read the Test Case ID.

If you need this code in the future, do not hard code the column numbers like I mentioned above. Read the first row(header) to determine the Run Mode column and the Test Case ID column and then follow the logic above. Put the text "Run Mode" in some application.properties which can be configured later on.